# How to fit TextBlock size to text size

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

i am working in silverlight for embedded windows and i want to fit text to the TextBlock as seen on picture, i want textBlock to fit text ( i want to remove yelow space in attached picture )

[image: Pic]

Can someone help me with this?

Best regards,
Luka

Here is the XAML i am currently using:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="FullTest.PUIsocUI"
d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="272">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="64" Grid.Row="1">
        <RadioButton x:Name="PowerMeasurement"      GroupName="PowerTabControls" IsChecked="True" Checked="PowerMeasurement_Checked" Unchecked="PowerMeasurement_Unchecked" Content="POWER" BorderThickness="0"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="PowerMode"             GroupName="PowerTabControls" Checked="PowerMode_Checked" Unchecked="PowerMode_Unchecked"/>      
        <RadioButton x:Name="PowerLimit"            GroupName="PowerTabControls" IsChecked="False" Click="PowerLimit_Click" Checked="PowerLimit_Checked" Unchecked="PowerLimit_Unchecked"/>     
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="PowerMeasurementPage" Margin="0,0,0,64" >
         <!-- tab page za meritev-->
            <TextBlock Text="POWER" Style="{StaticResource FunctionNameTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock Text="11.555" Style="{StaticResource ResultNameTextBlockStyle}"  />
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="PowerModePage" Margin="0,0,0,64">
        <!-- tab page za Mode-->
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="PowerLimitPage" Margin="0,0,0,64">
        <!-- tab page za Limita-->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="FunctionNameTextBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="ALTERNATE_GOTHIC#AlternateGothic2 BT"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="44"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="57,27,0,0"/>
    </Style>
```

this is what i want to get ->

[image: pic2]

Comment: Is your aim just to make alignment of the text item easier? If so just use a negative top margin. The problem is that a Text Block uses the padding defined by the Font itself to determine the size of the TextBlock.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want, make aligment easier :)

Comment: I can get the effect you want using margins on the TextBlock itself, but negative margins in the style setter seem to have no effect.

Comment: @LukaPivk Have you found a solution? Do share.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBlock Text="POWER" FontSize="44" FontWeight="SemiBold" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
   <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
     <CompositeTransform ScaleY="2"/>
   </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

In the example I've provided see the ScaleY declaration? Adjust that value to meet your needs. That's one way to accomplish that effect without using ViewBox. Another might be to convert that TextBlock in to a Path and adjust as necessary also, but it would have to be a static label for that to be useful.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: +1: Very creative solution. The font size needs to be adjusted, but that will avoid the font padding problem. Nice.

Comment: @HiTech Magic - Thanks, sometimes just have to work with what ya got and make lemonade. :)

Comment: This might be a solution for WP or silvelight 4,5 but not for silverlight for embedded windows and that is what i need.

Comment: Looks like it can be substituted for IXRCompositeTransform SetScaleY to accomplish the same thing specifically for embedded Windows, maybe worth a try. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg159743.aspx

Comment: Tnx Chris i will take a look at this, and post later this week

Answer (score 0):

The other way is even much simpler. You just have to **let** `TextBlock` to resize itself, it will arrange itself based on text. You should look into its container probably (probably paste some code?). Try setting `TextBlock` like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="POWER" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

**UPDATE** look into VS, to me it seems that it is just a font reserved space. Not sure how you can avoid that.

Comment: Hi,

I am using silverlight for embedded systems and it does not support ViewBox

Comment: And the key point was *"i want textBlock to fit text"* not the other way around.

Comment: HI, 
this is still the same, there is still white space above and below letters.

Comment: @LukaPivk, do not make us guessing, paste XAML

Comment: @LukaPivk, Not enough, please paste also its container. Also where is that yellow color taken from?

Comment: Ah sorry yelow color is just marking what i want to remove, i did that in paint. And see update in few sec

Answer (score 0):

In VS2015 you can do this easily with [TextLineBounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.textlinebounds) property (set it to Tight in your case). I use it in UAP, not sure it's available in Silverlight. However it gets truncated for lowercase letters like g, q, etc as posted here: [TextLineBounds snipping bottom of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829414/textlinebounds-snipping-bottom-of-letters)