# TextLineBounds snipping bottom of letters

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, textlinebounds

I'm using TextLineBounds in Windows 8.1 to align text of different font sizes on the baseline, such as

[image]

With the XAML looking like:

```
    <Grid x:Name="PageHeader">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       TextLineBounds="TrimToBaseline"
                       FontSize="50"
                       Text="OOO Big Font" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       TextLineBounds="TrimToBaseline"
                       FontSize="26"
                       Text="OOO SmallerFont" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="5"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       TextLineBounds="TrimToBaseline"
                       FontSize="20"
                       Text="OOO Even Smaller Font" />
        </Grid>
     </Grid>
```

When I resize the window, at some point (before the minimum size of 500) the descenders are clipped (and I've also seen the bottom pixel or two across entire line get clipped even when there are no descenders - resulting in artifacts like a flattened O).

[image]

The display elements do not change on the resize, there's no modification due to visual state, etc.

It seems like a bug, but not sure if there's a workaround (other than to abandon use of TextLineBounds).

Comment: I think that's the intended behavior, maybe a quick workaround would be just a quick `<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}"><Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/></Style>` though I did just notice you had it set on each block like that already, which I would have thought negated the need for your baseline trimming

Comment: I don't think it could be intended behavior since there something happening when the WIDTH of the grid changes, but the height of the TextBlocks don't.  In fact [this](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/11/xaml-text-improvements-in-windows-8-1/) says "A main reason to use this property is to control alignment of text elements, for example, to align the baseline of page headers"

Comment: The reason I say it looks intended, is if you go look at [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.textlinebounds) and their examples you see where you can expect your trim to occur (the yellow blocks that overlay the text portions in their examples.) Though I'm not sure what you mean with the width/height of the grid you mention.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I thought (hoped :)) that yellow overlay is intended to show how the text is measured, not rendered, and it's interesting that the remarks indicate applicability to "adjacent lines." So perhaps my use case (and the MSDN blog post?) is flawed  As for height/width, if you take the exact XAML I posted and pop it into a new Windows 8.1 page (no frills), it will render fine in landscape/portrait and when resizing to 1/2 the screen, but as you resize toward the min 500 px width at some point the descenders are chopped - so it seems inconsistent in its behavior.

Comment: I have just encountered this problem, and thanks for the discussion. Could it be that when the textbox gets too small to display all the text (and the "..." are shown) that it starts behaving as if there is a second line (so the "adjacent line" comes into play). That would be a bug, of course.